# XAML and Caliburn.Micro MVVM: Style resource referencing another style resource in a data template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

So, I am creating a UI in Visual Studio, and because of all of the repeated elements I am using a lot of elements in the Resources section of my user control. What I'm trying to do is iterate through items using another `StaticResource` in the file as the template for the items.

The problem is that the `Datatemplate` is of course switching the `DataContext` to the items it's iterating through. So I'm trying to figure out how to get the context of the static resources, which is on the context of the `UserControl`. I considered using relative sourcing, but then realized that `StaticResource` does not have that option and only lets you access the resources of the context.

Any suggestions for what to do here?

```
    <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="BeneficiaryList">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name_1}">
                        <Expander.Resources>
                            <utils:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
                        </Expander.Resources>
                        <!--Attempt at a proxy binding to access another style resource in the file. Does not work.-->
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource proxy.Person_Template}"/>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd simply give your UserControl a name, e.g. "`root`", and then bind using `ElementName`:

```
<ContentControl Style="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=DataContext.WhateverProperty}" />
```

Comment: Another question, how would I get to the `Style` element in the `<UserControl.Resources>` element? Is it as simple as just using `Path=DataContext.Resources.Person_Template`? Or is there a different access path I need to use?

Comment: Edit: I figured it out. It should be `Path=Resources[Person_Template]`

Comment: Could you try using {StaticResource Person_Template} instead of the binding?

Comment: That was my problem. It wasn't able to find the `StaticResource` because it was being referenced from the `DataContext` inside of an `ItemsTemplate`, which itself was inside of another template being stored in `.Resources`.